# Is there a way to create a stage that runs last, no matter the outcome of the pipeline?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a multistage yaml pipeline that looks something like this.
I need a stage that runs at the end of the pipeline run. No matter the outcome of the pipeline. even if it fails the stage should still run. Is there a way to define conditions or something that would be able to do this.

[image: pipeline]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sure the stage always runs, use the always() [condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml); and to make it run after the other stages, you can either put it last in the yaml file or define explicit dependencies:

```
- stage: runLast
  condition: always()
  dependsOn:
    - stageX
    - stageY
    - stageZ
```

Note: you *may* not want the stage to run if you've cancelled the pipeline; in that case, the condition to use is `succeededOrFailed()`